# Using python and flask, how can I pass a dynamic route argument to a new route called by the AJAX request?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have created a dynamic route in my Python Flask app to display a dynamic html template. At the top of the page there is a graph that is different for each page (the wins_graph variable). Each page initially displays just the way it should.

views.py (Initial Route)

```
@app.route('/sports/nba/<team_abbr>-spending-performance/')
def nba_spending_performance_team(team_abbr):
    team_query = NBAWinsvsSalary.query.filter_by(team_abbr=team_abbr).order_by(NBAWinsvsSalary.season).all()
    team_colors = 'RdBu'
    wins_graph = Functions.wins_plot(team_query, 'No Seasons', 'rgba(175, 27, 50, 1)', team_colors)
    return render_template('sports/nba/spending-performance-team.html', wins_graph)
```

sports/nba/spending-performance-team.html

```
<header>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="graph-container">
    <div class="graph-options">
    <label> Choose the plot type....</label>
        <span class="graph-options" id="atl_wins_graph">
            <button class="atl_wins_graph left selected" value="No Seasons">No Seasons</button>
            <button class="atl_wins_graph right" value="Seasons">Seasons</button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="graph" id="wins_graph">
        <script>
            var graphs = {{wins_graph | safe}};
            Plotly.plot('wins_graph',graphs,{});
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.3.1.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/plots.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see, there are two buttons above the graph. There is a second graph I want displayed, but only when the second button is clicked. I have written an AJAX call to handle this.

plots.js

```
$('.atl_wins_graph').on('click',function(){

$('#selected').html(this.value);
$('.atl_wins_graph').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');


    $.ajax({
        url: "/spending-wins/",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: { 'selected': this.value },
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            Plotly.newPlot('wins_graph', data );
        }
    });

});
```

And an additional route to correspond with the new graph.

views.py (Additional Route)

```
@app.route('/spending-wins/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def spending_change_wins():
    feature = request.args['selected']
    team_color = 'rgba(175, 27, 50, 1)'
    team_colors = 'RdBu'
    team_query = NBAWinsvsSalary.query.filter_by(team_abbr=team_abbr).order_by(NBAWinsvsSalary.season).all()
    graphJSON = wins_plot(team_query, feature, team_color, team_colors)
    return graphJSON
```

The problem is with the team_query variable in the additional route because I haven't defined team_abbr.

The error I receive is:

```
NameError: name 'team_abbr' is not defined
```

I understand why I am getting this error. If I define team_abbr with an actual value from the database, everything works the way it should. But that isn't a reasonable fix because now the route isn't dynamic.

I just can't figure out how to pass the team_abbr argument from the initial route to the additional route without having to use a redirect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you used `{{ url_for(something, team_abbr=team_abbr) }}` it will pass the variable between functions. But I think I've misunderstood too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the team abbreviation as an HTML5 `data` attribute and pass the abbreviation back as part of the `ajax` `data` value:

In `views.py`, pass the team abbreviation to the template:

```
@app.route('/sports/nba/<team_abbr>-spending-performance/')
def nba_spending_performance_team(team_abbr):
   team_query = NBAWinsvsSalary.query.filter_by(team_abbr=team_abbr).order_by(NBAWinsvsSalary.season).all()
   team_colors = 'RdBu'
   wins_graph = Functions.wins_plot(team_query, 'No Seasons', 'rgba(175, 27, 50, 1)', team_colors)
   return render_template('sports/nba/spending-performance-team.html', wins_graph, abbrev=team_abbr)
```

In `spending-performance-team.html`, render the `abbrev` value as a `data` attribute for each button:

```
<span class="graph-options" id="atl_wins_graph">
   <button class="atl_wins_graph left selected" value="No Seasons" data-abbr="{{abbrev}}">No Seasons</button>
   <button class="atl_wins_graph right" value="Seasons" data-abbr="{{abbrev}}">Seasons</button>
</span>
```

Now, in `plots.js`, update the `data` key of the `ajax` request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/spending-wins/",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    data: { 'selected': this.value, 'abbr':$(this).data('abbr')},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {
        Plotly.newPlot('wins_graph', data );
    }
});
```

Lastly, in `views.py` (Additional route):

```
@app.route('/spending-wins/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def spending_change_wins():
  feature = request.args['selected']
  team_color = 'rgba(175, 27, 50, 1)'
  team_colors = 'RdBu'
  team_query = NBAWinsvsSalary.query.filter_by(team_abbr=request.args.get('abbr')).order_by(NBAWinsvsSalary.season).all()
  graphJSON = wins_plot(team_query, feature, team_color, team_colors)
  return graphJSON
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Just a small clarification for anyone using this question. In the additional route, I had to remove 'flask.' from 'team_abbr=flask.request.arg.get('abbr')). This is because I had already imported request from flask at the top of my views.py file. I forgot to include that in my question.

Comment: @DustinWest Glad to help! Will remove the module name object from the answer

Answer (score 0):

In `sports/nba/spending-performance-team.html` create a hidden input with value of `team_abbr`, passed like `win_graph` is in the `nba_spending_performance_team` controller. Then have the JS get that value (something like `$("#team-abbr").value`) and pass it as an argument in ajax, then just like selected you have the team abbreviation.